# Why is a HTTPS NSURLSession connection only challenged once per domain?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, https, nsurlsession

When connecting via HTTPS to a server, I implement the `NSURLSessionDelegate` method `URLSession:didReceiveChallenge:completionHandler:` to implement some custom functionality.

The problem is that this delegate method is only being called the first time a request is made (subsequent requests do not invoke this method). My custom functionality requires the delegate method to be called for **every** request.

Here's an example:

```
- (IBAction)reload:(id)sender {
    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration ephemeralSessionConfiguration] delegate:self delegateQueue:nil];
    // Note that https://www.example.com is not the site I'm really connecting to.
    NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.example.com"];
    NSMutableURLRequest *URLRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:URL];

    [[session dataTaskWithRequest:URLRequest
                completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
                    // Response received here.
                }] resume];
}

#pragma NSURLSessionDelegate

- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session didReceiveChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge completionHandler:(void (^)(NSURLSessionAuthChallengeDisposition disposition, NSURLCredential *credential))completionHandler
{
    // Called only for the first request, subsequent requests do no invoke this method.
    completionHandler(NSURLSessionAuthChallengeUseCredential, [NSURLCredential credentialForTrust:challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust]);
}
```

Since I want the URLCredential to be per session or per task, I checked the `NSURLCredential` that I pass to `completionHandler`, and I found it has a `persistence` of `NSURLCredentialPersistenceForSession` (which is immutable), which seems correct.

I also checked `[NSURLCredentialStorage allCredentials]` and it's empty, so it's not caching the credentials there.

I noticed that if I subsequently make a request to a HTTPS URL with a different domain, the challenge is called for that domain once, so it is on a per domain basis.

So how come the challenge is only made once?

**EDIT**

Switching to the `NSURLSessionTaskDelegate` and using `URLSession:task:didReceiveChallenge:completionHandler:` makes no difference.

```
- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session task:(NSURLSessionTask *)task didReceiveChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge completionHandler:(void (^)(NSURLSessionAuthChallengeDisposition disposition, NSURLCredential *credential))completionHandler
{
    completionHandler(NSURLSessionAuthChallengeUseCredential, [NSURLCredential credentialForTrust:challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust]);
}
```

**EDIT** [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25746999/1305067)

**EDIT** Since there seems to be no way to fix this at the moment, I've filed an Apple bug report: 19072802

Comment: Did you found solution for your problem? I started to get same problem when moved to PROD environment. On PRE-PROD I all the time I got didReceiveChalleng. At this point for me it looks that it is related to backend.

Comment: I tested this recently and it seemed fixed (it always asks for auth). If I find my sample project I'll give it to you.

Comment: After reading the Apple docs I found out that for session-level challenges is responsible server. Needs to look into backend configuration/setup. If interested look for "session-level" here https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/NSURLSessionConcepts/NSURLSessionConcepts.html .

Comment: So my problem was fixed by disabling ssl session caching in nginx.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What you're really trying to do here is evaluate the trust of the server's credentials for each *request*.

[Technote 2232: HTTPS Server Trust Evaluation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2232/_index.html) describes HTTP trust evaluation at a high level, and goes into more detail about implementing it.

When you connect to a host using SSL/TLS, the host presents a set of cryptographic credentials. Your application (and potentially the user directly) must evaluate those credentials and decide if the can be trusted.

This is like looking at someone's driver's license or passport, and deciding wether they are who they say they are.

Imagine if you looked at someone's identification once for each word they speak. That would get tedius! It would not make sense unless the person changed, or their identification changed. iOS will perform trust evaluation if the server or it's credentials change.

This actually happens at the transport (socket) layer underneath HTTP, but Foundation thankfully exposes this higher up in APIs such as `NSURLConnection` and `NSURLSession` as a credential challenge for a given protection space. If the protection space (the host) or the server credentials change, a new credential challenge occurs. This will in turn prompt trust evaluation.

Since SSL/TLS is a socket-level security measure, the real work happens far below the Foundation URL loading system inside `SecureTransport`, the secure socket framework. `SecureTransport` maintains its own per-process TLS session cache. This is the layer you would have to circumvent to get the behavior you are looking for - you would need to clear the TLS session cache for each connection, or force `SecureTransport` to disregard the session cache for your process.

[Technical Q&A 1727: TLS Session Cache](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1727/_index.html) describes the `SecureTransport` session cache in more detail, and may provide some interesting options for circumventing the TLS cache (i.e. messing with DNS).

At this time there is no API for clearing or modifying the `SecureTransport` TLS session cache. You can file a radar requesting this functionality.

#### TL;DR;

*"So how come the challenge is only made once?"*
The result of the first TLS trust evaluation is cached by `SecureTransport` in the session cache.

There is not a way to control that particular behavior at this time.

You can try using some other HTTPS library or framework (such as OpenSSL), YMMV.

Comment: Great information @quellish, like you said, its seems like currently there's no way to properly circumvent the TLS session cache, so I filed a bug report 19072802

Comment: @quellish In the doc (which you posted) I found that NSURLSession maintains it's own TLS session cache. What I noticed as well that after moving to PROD environment I started to get problem that did receive challenge is not called, but on PRE-PORD I was getting all the time. I have feeling that it can be related to backend. Can it be?