# NSURLSession didReceiveChallenge called for every request

Tags: nsurlsession, authenticationchallenge

I have gone through this link

[Why is a HTTPS NSURLSession connection only challenged once per domain?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27065372/why-is-a-https-nsurlsession-connection-only-challenged-once-per-domain)

In case of NSURLConnection, didReceiveChallenge was not called for every request. In case of NSURLSession, it is called for every request. How can they behave differently if its dependent only on TLS session cache

Comment: Called for which protection space?  Is this in a single session or multiple sessions?  Code snippet?

Comment: It is for a single session.

Comment: Which protection space?